# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/foldername/public_html/event2.php on line 48 0 results

Tags: php, sql

could anyone help me or point me in the right direction?
I have googled this error before and tried to fix the error by their suggestions but it has not worked. It is probably something simple to fix. 
Thanks, CR.

```
<?php
 include_once 'NEE_Connection.php';
 $sql = "SELECT NEE_EventsNew.event_title, NEE_EventsNew.event_desc, NEE_EventsNew.event_sDate, NEE_EventsNew.event_eDate, NEE_EventsNew.event_price
 FROM NEE_EventsNew
 INNER JOIN NEE_Venue ON NEE_EventsNew.venue_id=NEE_Venue.venue_id;
 INNER JOIN NEE_Category ON NEE_EventsNew.category_id=NEE_Category.category_id;
 ORDER BY NEE_EventsNew.event_id";

 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 //line 48 below
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "  Title: " . $row["event_title"]. "<br>";
          echo "  Description: " . $row["event_desc"]. "<br>";
          echo "  Start Date: " . $row["event_sDate"]. "<br>";
          echo "  End Date: " . $row["event_eDate"]. "<br>";
          echo "  Price: £" . $row["event_price"]. "<br>";
       }
     } 
else {
     echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Your query is most likely failing and `$result` is Boolean `false`

Comment: do `var_dump( $result );` after `$result = $conn->query($sql);`